# Showing a AlertDialog in a onItemLongClick is giving a error about the parent what I have to do?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, onitemlongclicklistener

I am trying to show a dialog when the user do `onItemLongClick` of a Listview for confirm if the user wants do that but give me this error in the line of the `adb.show()`:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

with the folowing code:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
            adb.setView(view);
            adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");
            adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } });

            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //finish();
                } });
            adb.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I searched for answers but I dint saw about listview or longclick so i need help :(

**Added** the logcat, the line where it give the error is where appear `adb.show();`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3758)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:492)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:236)
at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:993)
at pt.isec.jogodememoria.MenuEscolheNivel$2.onItemLongClick(MenuEscolheNivel.java:119)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3121)
at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3070)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: infalte another view with the same layout like View view =         getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout,null); and then add it to dialog --> adb.setView(view);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy mistake, this is missing `AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();` and there is no need for the setView. You can still create a separate method and instantiate it for every long item click.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView
            .OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        createDialog(view);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Then create a separate method for your dialog:

```
public void createDialog(View view){

   AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //adb.setView(Main.this);
    adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");
    adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //finish();
        } });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

[image]

Comment: Give the same error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` in the same line of the `adb.show();`

Comment: But without setView give this error `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: Thanks for the help i wait no problem i talked with a friend and it says probably i have to create the builder outside because i am adding multiple times i have to check

Comment: i have to write write other answer to and test this in my code thanks check next what i go add to the main post

Answer (score 0):

I think that the line

```
adb.setView(view);
```

is wrong.

Because your are trying put the item view (view) like principal view for you Dialog.
If you comment these line, the code should be work.

You should be change this line

```
adb.show();
```

by this

```
AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();
dialog.show();
```

And put change your context (getBaseContext()) by YourActivity.this or getActivity().

Regards.

Comment: Without that give this error `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: i cannot do `YourActivity.this or getActivity(). ` because it expetcs a context not a activity

Answer (score 0):

### Try This First

```
  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                showDialog(view);
    
           return true;
            }
        });
    
    
        private void showDialog(View view) {
    
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                adb.setView(view);//try it first with this line if it doesnt work delete it 
                adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");
                adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    
                        Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } });
    
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //finish();
                    } });
                
                adb.create().show();
        }
```

if it didnt work out then create a custom Layout in which holds only the body of the dialog and then try this :

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    
                    showDialog(view);
        
               return true;
                }
            });

  private void showDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        final View customview = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(customview);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

i hope this will help you :)

Comment: Don´t compile give this error `Error:(88, 67) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()`

Comment: listen extract the alert dialg code to a new method and call the method from the listener

Comment: Listen i will give you a nice solution just wait a seconds i will be back :P

Answer (score 0):

Is because you are trying to use a view that has a parent, as you see you couldn't. The best way is inflating another view with the same layout as you want.

try to use another layout, with the same things:

and then:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
View newView = View.inflate(getBaseContext(),R.layout.my_layout,null);
adb.setView(newView);
adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");
adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});

adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //finish();
  }
});

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    adb.show();
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I cannot do `View newView = getLayoutInflater();` give compiling error `Error:(83, 41) error: incompatible types: LayoutInflater cannot be converted to View`

Comment: Oh my fault, use View.inflate(getBaseContext(),R.layout.my_layout,null); instead. Let me change it.

Comment: Now it show like other guy said almost the same answer of you but it show what i have in the my_layout i gonna put on main post the actual state thanks check what i go write

Comment: If you need to pass information, just get it first an then pass to new activity for example:                 ((TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.text_view)).setText(((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view)).getText());

Comment: Oh I didn´t see because was just one minute, but sorry.